# iOS RESideMenu usage with Storboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I want to use this Project with a Storyboard project:
https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

I followed the example-description for Storyboard, but the result issn´t right.
- created a new Single-View Applicaion project.
- Added de RESideMenu subclass and ViewControllers as descripted.

If I run this Project, all what I see, is the first ViewController, which i can "swipe" to the right, and then I see the second ViewController. 
So I think there is more to do, but can´t figure it out.

Would be nice, if someone could help me, thanks!

Comment: There is an example in https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu/tree/master/Examples/Storyboards

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu/tree/master/Examples/Storyboards. Just follow that example